# Problema con Endpoints al Desplegar E-commerce en Hostinger desde Terminal Local

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angular, express

Hola comunidad de Stack Overflow,
Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar desplegar un e-commerce en Hostinger desde mi terminal local. A continuación, proporciono detalles sobre el entorno y los pasos que he tomado hasta ahora:

1. **Entorno de Desarrollo:**

- Estoy corriendo el backend localmente en mi PC.
- La conexión a la base de datos de Hostinger ha sido establecida con éxito.
- El backend está corriendo en el puerto 4100, y los endpoints se muestran como activos.

2. **Intentos para Solucionar el Problema:**

- **Cambio de Puerto:** Intenté cambiar el puerto a 443, que es el puerto habilitado por Hostinger para HTTPS. Sin embargo, el programa no corrió correctamente ya que no se permiten puertos de tres dígitos.
- **Cambio de Ruta (Dominio):**
- Intenté cambiar la ruta (dominio) desde el frontend integrándole "/api", pero no se solucionó el problema.
- También probé cambiar la ruta a ":4100/api" desde el frontend, pero tampoco tuve éxito.

3. **Error Específico:**

- Cuando intento utilizar el e-commerce, obtengo un error 404 indicando que no puede encontrar los endpoints.
  Agradecería mucho cualquier orientación o sugerencia sobre cómo abordar este problema. ¿Hay alguna configuración adicional que deba tener en cuenta al desplegar en Hostinger? ¿Algún ajuste específico para asegurar la correcta conexión entre el backend y el frontend?
  ¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]